# Powershell loop through folder, search by file names and location then replace

Tags: powershell, search

I would like to use a loop for my program that grabs the file names of only the `.dll` in the folder and subfolders of that directory. It then searches a specified location/path for a `.dll` with the same file name and if it exists it replaces it. So far my program copies all files from one location to the other and once they are copied I need the above stated to be worked out.

My biggest issue is *how do you search by filenames in a loop at a specified location and if it exists, replace it*? Below code is locally in random places before I put the correct paths using servers and other drives.

```
#sets source user can edit path to be more precise  

$source = "C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\*"

 #sets destination 

$1stdest = "C:\Users\User\Music\Sample Music Location"

#copies source to destination 

Get-ChildItem $source -recurse | Copy-Item -destination $1stdest 

#takes 1stdest and finds only dlls to variable  

#not sure if this is right but it takes the .dlls only, can you do that in the foreach()? 

Get-ChildItem $1stdest -recurse -include "*.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you'll need to edit your paths back in.  Also, note that `$1stDest` was changed to enumerate the list of files in the destination folder.

The logic goes through all of the files in $source, and looks for a match in `$1stDest`.  if it finds some, it stores them in `$OverWriteMe`.  The code then steps through each file to be overwritten and copies it.

As written, it uses `-WhatIf`, so you'll have a preview of what would happen before running it.  If you like what you see, remove the `-WhatIf` on line 15.

```cs
$source = "c:\temp\stack\source\"

 #sets destination 

$1stdest = get-childitem C:\temp\stack\Dest -Recurse

#copies source to destination 

ForEach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $source -recurse) ){

    If ($file.BaseName -in $1stdest.BaseName){
        $overwriteMe = $1stdest | Where BaseName -eq $file.BaseName 
        Write-Output "$($file.baseName) already exists @ $($overwriteMe.FullName)" 
        $overwriteMe | ForEach-Object {
             copy-item $file.FullName -Destination $overwriteMe.FullName -WhatIf
             #End of ForEach $overwriteme
             }

        #End Of ForEach $file in ...
        } 


}
```

## OutPut

```
1 already exists @ C:\temp\stack\Dest\1.txt
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\temp\stack\source\1.txt Destination: C:\temp\stack\Dest\1.txt".
5 already exists @ C:\temp\stack\Dest\5.txt
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\temp\stack\source\5.txt Destination: C:\temp\stack\Dest\5.txt".
```

Comment: There is an error with the code above. "You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator." How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try and copy it again, I think I had an extra space before.  If it still fails, reply to this thread with a pastebin link to your exact code and I'll help you figure it out.